# Swift escaping function

Tags: json, swift, closures

i followed a tutorial from youtube how to get data from a json, but i do not understand all the steps.
This is the function :

```
 func downloadJSON (completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
    
    let url = URL (string: "https://api.github.com/repos/\(details!.full_name)/readme")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        
        if error == nil {
            do {
                self.read = try JSONDecoder().decode(Readm.self, from: data!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completed()
                }
            }catch {
                print (error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

}

And this is how i am calling it

```
 downloadJSON {
        if let content = self.read?.content {
            self.textViewScroll.text = self.base64Decoded(word: content)
        }
```

I see that i'm using a @escaping, if i get it right, the "downloadJson" in the viewDidLoad is calling after the func ? What is with "completed()" in the DispatchQueue.main.async.
If somebody can help me with an explanation based on this example i'll be grateful. Thx !

Comment: `completed()` links to `completed: @escaping () -> ()`, you would have named it `somethingElse: () -> ()`, you'd call `somethingElse()`. It'd be `completed: (Int) -> ()`, it's be `completed(3)` (or any relevant number). It's escaping because indeed it can be called after you reach the last `}` of the method (to explain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake about calling downloadJSON.

```
         func downloadJSON (completed: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
            
            let url = URL (string: "https://api.github.com/repos/\(details!.full_name)/readme")
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
                
                if error == nil {
                    do {
                        self.read = try JSONDecoder().decode(Readm.self, from: data!)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            completed(true)
                        }
                    }catch {
                        completed(false)
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
```

Then calling func is:

```
    func downloadJSON()
    {
        [weak self] (result) in
        guard let self = self else {return}
        if result
        {
         if let content = self.read?.content {
         self.textViewScroll.text = self.base64Decoded(word: content)}
        }
        else
        {
          print("error")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your's closure "completed" escaped to other closure in DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }.

It's escaped because it owned by other object(escaped to it), to other closure in this case.